# Why does fopen thown errno:22 when I use the file name with colon in Android?

Tags: android, c++, c, linux, file-io

When I use the file name with colon like `2012-12-12 12:00:00`, fopen will be failed and the error is `Invalid argument`.If I change the file name to `2012-12-12 12-00-00` it goes rightly.What does errno `Invalid argument` mean? I've tried to run command in Android by `adb shell`, I tried `touch` a file with colon in name, it was failed, but If I use `vi` to new a file with colon in name, it goes rightly.What is the matter with this?And I've check the path, no problem with it.

```
errno = 0;
FILE *fp = fopen("/sdcard/2012-12-12 12:00:00", "a");
if (fp == NULL) {
    strerror(errno)   // Invalid argument
    return;
}

fprintf(fp, "%s", "something");
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: You should print `strerror(errno)` in addition of `errno` (or use `perror`)

Comment: On my plain Ubuntu Linux system, errno 22 is `EINVAL`, as in "invalid argument".

Comment: Yes, when I use `strerror(errno)`, it print `Invalid argument`, what does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose the problem arises because the colon `:` is used as a path-list separator under *NIX systems (e.g. to separate the pathnames listed in the `PATH` environment variable). Probably some internal processing went awry because of this.

Comment: That was my first guess too, but then why does vi succeed in creating the file?

Comment: @unwind Well, I'm not sure if `:` is actually illegal at kernel level, so maybe it *can* be put in a filename, but how it is processed depends on the specific tool.

Comment: The problem is not the path-list separator. The valid characters in file names depend on the file system, and according to the "possible duplicate" linked above, the colon is not allowed on a FAT32 file system.

Comment: @MartinR Yep! Nice find!

Comment: First Google hit for "android invalid file name colon" :-)

Comment: @MartinR I googled it too, but probably didn't use the right keywords combinations. My google-fu is failing me, argh! :-)